# Error: How to serialize data from getStaticProps : Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm working with Next.js, I tried accessing data but got this error:

```
Error: Error serializing `.profileData` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/profile/[slug]".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.
```

My code:

```
import { getAllBusinessProfiles } from '../../lib/api';

const Profile = ({ allProfiles: { edges } }) => {
    return ( 
        <>
          <Head>
            <title>Profile</title>
          </Head>

          <Hero />

          <section>
            {edges.map(({ node }) => (
              <div key={node.id}>
                  <Link href={`/profile/${node.slug}`}>
                    <a> {node.businessInfo.name} </a>
                  </Link>
              </div>
            ))}
          </section>

        </>
     );
}
 
export default Profile;

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const allProfiles = await getAllBusinessProfiles();
    return {
      props: {
        allProfiles
      }
    };
  }
```

getAllBusinessProfiles from api.js:

```
const API_URL = process.env.WP_API_URL;

async function fetchAPI(query, { variables } = {}) {
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };

  const res = await fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables })
  });

  const json = await res.json();
  if (json.errors) {
    console.log(json.errors);
    console.log('error details', query, variables);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch API');
  }
  return json.data;
}

export async function getAllBusinessProfiles() {
    const data = await fetchAPI(
      `
      query AllProfiles {
        businessProfiles(where: {orderby: {field: DATE, order: ASC}}) {
          edges {
            node {
              date
              title
              slug
              link
              uri
              businessInfo {
                name
                title
                company
                image {
                  mediaItemUrl
                  altText
                }
                highlight
                phone
                city
                country
                facebook
                instagram
                email
                website
                profiles {
                  profile
                  profileInfo
                }
                extendedProfile {
                  title
                  info
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      
      `
    );
    return data?.businessProfiles;
};
```

What could be the error here? I used the getStaticProps method on Next.js but got the error above instead. Please, check. Thanks.

The error:
Server Error
Error: Error serializing `.profileData` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/profile/[slug]".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.

I don't know what could cause this though.

Comment: Going to repeat what I mentioned in your last question: Some field in your allProfiles object is `undefined` which is not serializable as JSON so can't be returned from getStaticProps. Either convert those to `null` or omit them entirely.

Comment: How will I fix it? Please

Comment: did you fix it ?

Comment: I have the same error. Could you fix it?

Answer (score 21):

Add [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) when calling an asynchronous function that returns an object.

Try modifying your `getStaticProps` function like this.

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const profiles = await getAllBusinessProfiles();
    const allProfiles = JSON.stringify(profiles)

    return {
        props: {
             allProfiles
        }
   };
}
```

> The `JSON.stringify()` method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Is there a way how to unserialize the data automatically without having to call `JSON.parse()` on the props in the component manually?

Comment: you can serialize and unserialize at the same time ```JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(profiles))```. this allows you to send a normal object to your component @Qwerty

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue using Mongoose and Next.js.

To solve it: I switched from convert require to import then wrapped my result in `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));`.

**Good:** `import mongoose from 'mongoose';`

**Bad:** `const mongoose = require('mongoose');`

Comment: It worked well for me using firestore. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I was working with redux with next js and the reason was one of the fields in the default state I set it to undefined. Instead I used `null`:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  products: [],
  loading: false,
  error: undefined,
  cart: [],
};
```

`error:undefined` was causing the error. Because "undefined" cannot be serialized:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const allProfiles = await getAllBusinessProfiles();
    return {
      props: {
        allProfiles
      }
    };
  }
```

you are returning "allProfiles" which is the result of async `getAllBusinessProfiles()` which is either returning undefined, error or one of the fields of the returned object is undefined. "error" object is not serializable in javascript

Comment: I was trying to export boolean value `context.preview` from `getStaticProps` and whenever I exited the preview mode, the value came `undefined`. I simply returned `!!context.preview` and the error was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same serialization error when accessing a Vercel system environment variable in `getStaticProps`.

Using `JSON.stringify` did not do the trick, but `String()` worked. My code:

```js
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const deploymentURL = String(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERCEL_URL);

  return {
    props: {
      deploymentURL,
    },
  };
}
```

Thanks to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/26582) for the inspiration

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `undefined`, you have to use `null` as the value for your variables.

Note that the error shows you exactly which variable is using `undefined` as its value. Just modify its value to be `null`.

*The value 'undefined' denotes that a variable has been declared, but hasn't been assigned any value. So, the value of the variable is 'undefined'. On the other hand, 'null' refers to a non-existent object, which basically means 'empty' or 'nothing'.*

Source: [[1]](https://The%20value%20%27undefined%27%20denotes%20that%20a%20variable%20has%20been%20declared,%20but%20hasn%27t%20been%20assigned%20any%20value.%20So,%20the%20value%20of%20the%20variable%20is%20%27undefined%27.%20On%20the%20other%20hand,%20%27null%27%20refers%20to%20a%20non-existent%20object,%20which%20basically%20means%20%27empty%27%20or%20%27nothing%27.)

Answer (score 0):

try this, it worked for me:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const APP_URL = process.env.PUBLIC_NEXT_WEB_APP_URL;
  const res = await fetch(`${APP_URL}/api/projects`);
  const projects = await res.json();
  return {
    props: {
      projects: projects?.data,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue while trying to find a match in the array of data using the id. The issue I had was the items in the array had ids which were numbers while the value I was getting from params was a string. So all i did was convert the number id to a string to match the comparison.

```js
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const coffeeStore = coffeeStoreData.find(
    (store) => store.id.toString() === params.slug[0]
  );
  return {
    props: {
      coffeeStore,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `getStaticProps()` function, after fetching your data it will be in json format initially, but you should change it as follow:

```
     const res = await fetch(`${APP_URL}/api/projects`);
     const data = JSON.parse(res);
```

now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

install a package called **babel-plugin-superjson-next** and **superjson** and added a **.babelrc** file with these contents:

```html
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": ["superjson-next"]
}
```

see this topic : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11498.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem too where I was fetching data through [apollo](https://www.apollographql.com) directly inside of getStaticProps. All I had to do to fix the error was add the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to the return.

```
    return {
    props: {
      data: { ...data }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return { props: { allProfiles: allProfiles || null } }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you call api you should use try catch. It will resolve error.

**Example:**

```
import axios from "axios";
    export const getStaticProps = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get("http:...");
            const data = response.data;
            return {
                props: {
                    posts: data
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Hope help for you !

Answer (score 0):

put res from API in Curly Brackets

```
const { res }  = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api", {data})
return { props: { res } }
```