# nextjs auto convert mongodb ObjectId to string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

This is an issue I am struggeling for a while, once you reference an ObjectId within a document in MongoDB and later serialise it as JSON, it will throw an error

```
Error: Error serializing `.kurs` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/course".
Reason: `object` ("[object Uint8Array]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.
```

This is due to that ObjectId is not autoconvertible to string, is there any fix for that or a good approach?

Comment: Could you provide is with more code? it's hard to visualize how it's currently being implemented in your code without a reference. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can call the toString() method on these properties to get the correct string values.

Or write something with:

```
JSON.stringify(dataObject)
```

EDITED: something like this work in my code

```
export async function getStaticData() {
    const data = await getAllData();
    const allData = JSON.stringify(data)

    return {
        props: {
             allData
        }
   };
}
```

Comment: Hi, that does not work, was my first try ofc..

Comment: I've edited my answer..otherwise this might help(?) : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106776/error-how-to-serialize-data-from-getstaticprops-next-js)

Comment: thanks for the hint, I tried that as well JSON.stringify() and after JSON.parse(), it does not work for me same issue, its strange that it works for you!?

Comment: Yes, could you share with us your code?