# Nodejs re parse JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, next.js

I am unsure why with mongodb and Nextjs I am having to re do `JSON.parse` on data that I have fetching from MongoDB.

```
function PodcastUpload({ data }) {

  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  var eD = JSON.parse(data);
  eD = eD[0]
```

the data is from

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
   
      const token = await getSession(ctx)
      const data =  await getLatestEpisodeData(token,ctx.params.podcastName)
      
      return { props: { data } }
  
}
```

which gets the data from

```
export async function getLatestEpisodeData(token, showname) {
   
 
    if (token) {
      // Signed in
      const uuid = token.uuid;
  
  
     try {
          const client = await clientPromise;
          const db = client.db("DRN1");
         
          const shows = await db
              .collection("episode")
              //.findOne({show_b: showname})
              //.toArray()
              .find({'show_b': showname})
              .sort({_id:-1})
              .limit(1)
              .toArray();
  
              return(JSON.stringify(shows));
          
         
      } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
      }
  
    }
}
```

I have tried to remove the `JSON.stringify` however that brings up a `SerializableError: Error serializing` .data`returned from`getServerSideProps `in "/staff/podcasts/[podcastName]/upload".`

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Error: How to serialize data from getStaticProps : Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66106776/error-how-to-serialize-data-from-getstaticprops-next-js)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging `data` in your `getServerSideProps` ?
I usually get this error when one of my `props` is `undefined`